# Create a Binary Image

Tags: image, matlab

I have a question concerning the creation of a binary image in MATLAB.
I want to create a binary image with `3907x3713` pixels. Each pixel is represented by a position in a matrix (I presume). Each pixel has to be black (so value `0` I guess) except for the pixels between `1000-1500` (`x`-axis) and `2000-2500` (`y`-axis), these have to be white (value `256` I guess).

First of all I create a matrix with `3907` rows and `3713` columns. I fill these up with zeros (through the function `zeros`). But than I get stuck to find an easy way to replace some with the value `256`.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: How about `im(1000:1500,2000:2500) = 255`? If the type is double, then 1 corresponds to white. Only for uint8, 255 (and not 256!) is white.

Comment: I will try that right away, thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0):

**zeros** function returns an array of **double**.

To create a really binary image with only black and white colors, convert your array to **logical** type:

```
im=logical(zeros(3907, 3713));
```

This will help to use significally (64 times) less memory.

In such image 0 is used for black, 1 is used for white. No other values are allowed.

So, to create some white pixels use

```
im(1000:1500,2000:2500) = 1;
```